# Bootstrap & Internet Explorer 11 issues

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I'm having a small formatting problem with my Internet Explorer 11.

Here is the picture from Google Chrome (THIS IS PERFECT):

[image]

Here is the picture from Internet Explorer 11

[image]

Here is the code:

```css
.bottomRightBox {
  height: 170px; 
  width: 310px; 
  /* background-color: #4B92DB; 
  border: 1px black solid; //BOTTOM RIGHT BOX BORDER */ 
}

#contactsPicture {
  align: left; 
  valign: top;
  height: 98px;
  /* padding-top: 10px; //PADDING FOR CONTACT PICTURE */
}

#contactImg {
  width: auto;
  height: 148px;
}

.contactsPictureName {
  color: black!important;
  font-weight: normal!important;
  padding-left: 15px!important;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

#rightBottomHeading {
  float: right; 
  clear: right; 
  padding-right:176px;
  font-size: 18px!important;
  font-weight: bold!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-12 col-md-4" style="padding-right: 0px;">
  <h4 id="rightBottomHeading">Office 365 Contacts</h4>
  
  <hr id="bottomRightLineBreaker"/>
  
  <div class="bottomRightBox">
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr valign="top" id="ctl00_m_g_63062bfa_96b4_4d90_b7c4_92ac5983dbfe_ctl00_uxGenericListView_ctrl0_ctl09_genericPicRow">
      <td id="contactsPicture">
        <div class="UserPhoto">
          <a href="IMAGE LINK" target="_blank" style="padding-right: 5px;"><img id="contactImg" src="IMAGE URL" alt="A" /></a>
          <a href="mailto:Portalhelp" style="padding-left: 5px;"><img id="contactImg" src="IMAGE URL" alt="P" /></a>
        </div>
      </td></tr>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td style="width: 106px" valign="top">
        <div class="contactsPictureName">
          <a href="PICTURE LINK" target="_black" style="color: black;"><p id="name" style="width: auto; float: left; clear: none;">NAME</p></a>
          <a href="URL" style="color: black;"><p id="name" style="width: auto; float: right; clear: none; margin-right: 45px;">PORTALHELP</p></a>
        </div>
      </td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any input with CSS formatting and styling would be highly appreciated. Currently using Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Why using tables within inline styles instead of CSS?

Comment: The *only* Bootstrap CSS I see in your code is your initial column declaration. What makes you think this is specific to Bootstrap, and not the `float` implementation and fixed widths you're applying via your custom CSS?

Comment: Are you guys suggesting that I wrap it in div's instead of tables? The only reason that I used tables was because I had success on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it guys!

Thanks to Girdharilal and his attempt I was able to use:

```css
.UserPhoto a {
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
}
```

which ended up working perfectly.

Comment: Flexbox is an *excellent* solution but you should know that IE11 support is considered 'partial' due to its extreme bugginess.  If you do opt for a Flexbox solution you might consider updating to Bootstrap 4, which uses Flexbox by default.

Comment: I'll definitely have to familiarize myself with it a lot more, I mainly use Google Chrome and our employer website isn't accessible on any cross-browser website.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach to your display method.  Rather than relying on a bunch of custom css and `float` declarations, why not use the Grid for this situation?  Consider the following implementation:

```css
.contactBox {
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    
    <!-- The Left Column (Implied but never specified) -->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
      <p>This area is intentionally left blank.</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Your Right Column -->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <h4>Office 365 Contacts</h4>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="contactBox col-xs-6 col-md-4 text-center">
          <a href="#userPhotoLink"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x150" class="img-responsive" /></a>
          <a href="#userEmailLink">Name</a>
        </div>

        <div class="contactBox col-xs-6 col-md-4 text-center">
          <a href="#userPhotoLink"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x150" class="img-responsive" /></a>
          <a href="#userEmailLink">Name</a>
        </div>

        <div class="contactBox col-xs-6 col-md-4 text-center">
          <a href="#userPhotoLink"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x150" class="img-responsive" /></a>
          <a href="#userEmailLink">Name</a>
        </div>

        <div class="contactBox col-xs-6 col-md-4 text-center">
          <a href="#userPhotoLink"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x150" class="img-responsive" /></a>
          <a href="#userEmailLink">Name</a>
        </div>

        
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above code we're relying more heavily on the Bootstrap 3.x `Grid` component as well as a few other utility classes.  An added bonus is that by relying more heavily on Bootstrap you have an opportunity to offer better responsive behavior.

It really only requires one custom line of CSS; `.contactBox` ... which is really only there to ensure that you have proper bottom padding without the need to re-iterate `row` or add line breaks.

You may need to expand the snippet to see how the layout can adjust depending on screen resolution.  Alternatively, you can view the same code via the following Bootply link: https://www.bootply.com/LK0cVLrCBm

Comment: Thanks for the advice Robert! I'll start on getting it formatted into a div.